# Where should I declare variables if the function is called so many types

Tags: c, optimization, coding-style

I have an **IRQ handler**, it's called each time the user press a key on his keyboard, hence this function might be called so many time in a short range. Right now, inside the handler I declare two variables.

I **wonder if it's better to move those variables to global scope or should I leave them inside the function?** I know that in most of the cases global scope is preferable but I have other functions in the source file that I don't want to be able to access those variables and even see them.

```c
Or here
// unsigned int scancode;
// char *key;
irqreturn_t irq_kbdh_handler(void)
{
    unsigned int scancode;
    char *key;
}
```

As well I'm also concered about readability, optimiziation and just basic C coding standards.

Comment: `I know that in most of the cases global scope is preferable` who told you that? Generally it all depends on context, but as a rule of thumb, the more local sth is, the better. And then all sorts of problems like data exchange kick in... ;)

Comment: @alagner I meant to say that it is preferable if the function is called SO MANY times, it just common sense but if I might be wrong. Declaring the same variable over and over  ruins the performance?

Comment: Creating int or char? I wouldn't bother. Declaring/copying a several hundreds or thousands of bytes is sth else than several bytes. Generally, for optimizations one should measure first. Provided performance is ever a problem. Again, this is highly general answer, there are exceptions to this etc. but I'd care about readability and architecture first. Especially for trivial cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I declare variables if the function is called so many <strike>types</strike> times (?)

> I'm also concerned about readability, optimization and just basic C coding standards.

Declare variables local, inside the function, unless you have a proven reason otherwise.  OP's concerns are [premature](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).

A *keyboard* handler is *not* a high frequency called handler.